# Avalonia how using easing for color transition

Tags: c#, xaml, avaloniaui, avalonia

I want to make pretty background filling for my buttons. Color filling want started from center (like default Android animation for click). I reading official guide, but my code dont give that effect (only smoothing change color, without easing). Easing not working for me, only duration...

```
<Style Selector="Button">
    <Setter Property="Transitions">
        <Transitions>
            <BrushTransition Property="Background" Duration="0:0:0.5" Easing="CircularEaseInOut"/>
        </Transitions>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Sorry for my pure explanation, [this](https://codepen.io/wenza/pen/PZLQwm) CSS animation looks like my wish.

Comment: That isn't just a color transition. You need to start looking at rendering shapes on the UI and animating them based on the cursor position and the left click event. Honestly not sure where I'd start with this to be honest. Possibly editing the default button style.

Comment: Thanks. Easing not work for me in this task?

Comment: Easings change the animation speed in time, not the brush properties